# How many non-Doctor regenerations have we seen on-screen?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, regeneration

Regeneration in *Doctor Who* was a device created to explain the recasting of the main character, the Doctor himself. But it's something all Time Lords are capable of, and occasionally we've seen Time Lords other than the Doctor regenerate on-screen. E.g. the Master has [regenerated once on-screen, and an unknown number of times off-screen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/109981/31394). My question is:

**how many regeneration events, other than the Doctor's, have appeared on-screen?**

<sub>Main canon only (as far as such a thing exists in Doctor Who): the TV series, Old and New, plus the McGann film.</sub>

Comment: An interesting example of a case where we *should* have seen regenerations but did not was The Deadly Assassin. A rather bizarre story; it establishes that Time Lords can regenerate 12 times but none of the Time Lords killed regenerate. The only story in classic Who without a companion. And a thoroughly redundant title; a non-deadly assassin would by definition not be an assassin.

Comment: In "The Impossible Astronaut" the Doctor is shot twice and seemingly killed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not many

- Although the actual regeneration isn't shown on-screen, in "[Planet of the Spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Spiders)" we see that the Doctor's old mentor K'anpo Rimpoche has regenerated into Cho-Je, a character introduced earlier in the story<sup>1, 2</sup>
- In "[Destiny of the Daleks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny_of_the_Daleks)", we see Romana "trying on" various regenerations, although the actual regenerative process is not shown on-screen, until she eventually settles on the body played by Lalla Ward:
- The Master (Jacobi to Simm) in "[Utopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(Doctor_Who))"
- Melody Pond to Mels in "[Day of the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon)":
- Mels to River Song in "[Let's Kill Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Kill_Hitler)"
- The Time Lord General in "[Hell Bent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_Bent_(Doctor_Who))"
- A debateable one<sup>3</sup>, but K-9 sort-of regenerates (it's referred to as being caused by a "regeneration unit") in the first episode of his [2009 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-9_(TV_series)):

Finally, though not really a regeneration, it seems worth mentioning that we see the Master taking over a new body in "[The Keeper of Traken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keeper_of_Traken)":

---

<sup>1</sup> Wibbly-wobbly...

<sup>2</sup> Nod to Elliot Frisch for reminding me of this one in comments.

<sup>3</sup> As John Sensebe points out in comments, *K-9* isn't a BBC-licensed show, so it occupies a weird canon-space. I'm inclined to leave it, though, mainly because I think it's funny.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch As I recall, only the Doctor actually regenerates in that one. Also, *Fatal Death* isn't usually considered "canon" (with the normal *Doctor Who* canonicity disclaimers)

Comment: True. Planet of the Spiders. K'anpo / Cho-Je.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ah yes, forgot about that one; the actual regeneration isn't shown on-screen, but it's at least as fair as Romana's, so I'll add it in

Comment: The K-9 series isn't canon, so that one is *very* debatable. You're missing the regeneration of K’anpo in "Planet of the Spiders", which is special since that was the first time the word "regeneration" was used to describe the process. It's also a pretty weird one, for spoilerish reasons.

Comment: No worries; regeneration was seldom seen & "mysterious". Maybe The Watcher from Logopolis deserves a mention too? Also, the Minyans of Minyos in [Underworld](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Underworld_(TV_story)).

Comment: @JohnSensebe You're right about *K-9* (and I added a note to that effect), but I find it funny so I'm leaving it in

Comment: Cho-Je was a forward projection of K'anpo's soul, so no wibbly-wobbly there. Just weirdness. Some fans speculate that the Watcher was somehow similar.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm deliberately leaving out the Watcher because that's still the Doctor. Also (although it is *called* regeneration) I'm not sure if what happens in "Underworld" is quite the same thing. I'll have to ponder it more deeply

Comment: We see the Master take over another body (Eric Roberts') in the movie.

Comment: I like how the various rejected Romanas are either shown from behind (no face) or don't speak. I'm pretty sure that allowed them to get away with not crediting the actresses and paying them significantly less (and probably no royalties).

Comment: If Cho-Je counts then surely so does Borusa, Azmael, Rassilon (Mathews -? Dalton, Dalton -> Sumpter), The Master (Roberts -? Jacobi, Jacobi-> Simm)

Answer (score 2):

If you only count on-screen regenerations, there have been five:

- River song regenerates twice, in "Day of the Moon" and "Let's Kill Hitler"
- The Master regenerates on-screen once, in "Utopia"
- An anonymous guard regenerates in "Hell Bent"
- In classic Who, a Time Lord named Azmael commits suidice by regeneration in "The Twin Dilemma". (This one is debatable -- he doesn't actually regenerate, he dies by forcing a regeneration when he has none left.)

We know the Master regenerated several other times, but not on-screen. Romana also shows up in a number of forms, but the regenerations always happen off-screen.

Also of note, as of "Day of the Doctor", we have seen *all* of The Doctor's regenerations on-screen. The regeneration sequence from Eight -> War -> Nine was originally not shown, but "Day of the Doctor" and "Night of the Doctor" fill that gap.

Comment: We haven't actually seen the regeneration from Troughton to Pertwee, especially if you believe in Season 6b.

Comment: @JohnSensebe Interesting, I didn't hear about [that](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Season_6B) before...

Comment: Does Jenny in 'The Doctors Daughter' count as regeneration?

Comment: On the DVD of "The War Games", one of the special features is an excerpt of a fan-made film called "Devious" which does show the regeneration from Troughton to Pertwee, via an "interim" Doctor played by Tony Garner. Filming began in 1991 after Troughton was dead, so they used stock (colour) footage of him (I think taken from "The Two Doctors"), but the Garner-to-Pertwee sequence was filmed in 1995 and Jon Pertwee actually appeared in the film, not just in stock footage. It was his last performance as the Doctor before he died the following year.